# How to link ArcGIS Online content to my organization's own ArcGIS Online Home Page?

Tags: arcgis-online

My organization has an ArcGIS Online account.  We have jumped through all the hoops to set up our Home Page.  However, we now notice that if someone just logs into ArcGIS Online (the main site, not our organization's), while they can search our content, there is no way to automatically link to our ArcGIS Online Home Page.  Any ideas?  We want to direct traffic to our page.

If it is the only option: I have created a hyperlinked thumbnail that leads to our site.  How can I prioritize it so that it always pops to the top of the list when its Tags are searched for?